# stty RAW console in C

Tags: c, call, system, stty

I'm trying to build my own console and I'm using the below statement to get RAW access so I can implement some advanced features such as implementing the auto suggest feature that's implemented in a BASH shell by pressing the TAB key.

```
system("/bin/stty raw")
```

When using this, the enter key (and others) doesn't behave normally and when I press enter, it displays ^M and doesn't go to the next line.

1. How do I set the RAW console to go to the next line when it receives ^M
2. Also can I set the Shell to NOT display the keys pressed so I can send the char back to the console with putchar() (so ^M doesn't display when pressed).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I set the RAW console to go to the next line when it receives ^M

You write an appropriate control code to the console when you read an ^M. The whole point of *raw* mode is that the console does *not* do things like recognize line ends, backspaces, etc., etc., because you want to handle them yourself. Once you do that, you need to handle all those things.

> can I set the Shell to NOT display the keys pressed

Sure. Turn off `echo`. With the `stty` command, you would use `stty raw -echo` but if you're doing this from a C program, you'd be much better off using the terminal API. See [`man tcsetattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr)